# Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/build.gradle' line: 27

Tags: react-native, expo

`[stderr]
Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/build.gradle' line: 27
[stderr]

- What went wrong:
  [stderr]
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'NileCash'.
  [stderr]

> Cannot use project dependencies in a script classpath definition.
> [stderr]

- Try:
  [stderr]

> Run with --stacktrace
> [stderr]
> option to get the stack trace.
> [stderr]
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> [stderr]
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> [stderr]

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  [stderr]
  BUILD FAILED in 1m 4s
  Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.`

Pls help i got this problem, after ease build -p android --profile preview
I need to build successfully pls